# How to prevent websocket opening handshake timeout?

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to make a connection to a socket.io session. The connection is easily established, however, if I am idle for a short duration I get this error in my console:

`websocket.js:116 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=PwzuR5tNmPmZfj0UAAAB' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out`

I tried fixing the issue by setting `pingTimeout` and `pingInterval` but to no avail. I am not sure how to fix this or what is causing this.

On a side note, I am trying to read and understand the socket.io docs and am still not clear about what `ping` and `pong` packets exactly are. Does the client have to manually interact with the socketio server in order for it to receive pong packets or will it still receive pongs if say the client interacts with an http server on the same host ?

Comment: I have the same issue and I couldn't find anything about it. Did you manage to solve it or get any more information about the root cause of the problem?